# Why does Xcode give this error instead of undeclared identifier error?

Tags: c++, xcode, std, ifstream

Xcode LLVM Clang for the below sample getline_n(pipe, line, 50); gives and error:

```
No viable conversion from 'std::ifstream' 

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::ifstream pipe;
    pipe = std::ifstream {};
    pipe.open("/somefolder/pipe");
    std::string line{};
    getline_n(pipe, line, 50);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I change it to:

```
getline_n(pipe, line);
```

I get the expected error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'getline_n'
```

I believe this is a bug in Xcode.  Thoughts?